# Compact, incomplete semi-Riemannian manifold of constant curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

In the Riemannian setting, *Hopf-Rinow* tells us that *any compact Riemannian manifold is complete*. The *Clifton-Pohl torus* gives a counter example for indefinite metrics.

However, in the Lorentz setting, *Klingler* proved *a compact manfiold of constant curvature is complete*. The proof relies on a property of $O(n-1,1)$.

So my question is: Are there known compact semi-Riemannian manifolds of constant curvature which are not complete (hence of signature $(p,q)$ with $q\geq2$)?

**PS**

- Connectedness always assumed
- dim$(M)\geq2$

Comment: At least in the zero curvature case, this is an open problem (a special case of the Marcus conjecture on completeness of compact flat affine manifolds admitting a parallel volume form).